# How to render pdf generated from jasper reports in html <object> tag

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I am working on a struts2 project and come across a problem to display pdf report generated by JasperReport Server in the `<object>` tag.

Following are the jars i am using:

- struts2-core-2.3.16.jar
- jasperreports-5.5.0.jar
- jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.15.jar
- and many other jars.

Following is the code snippet for my action method.

```
public String salesReportHtml() {
    try {
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < tables.getTable("RS1").size(); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < tables.getTable("RS2").get(i).size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(j);
                head.put(headerColumn.get(j), tables.getTable("RS1").get(i).get(headerColumn.get(j)));

            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tables.getTable("RS2").size(); i++) {
            field = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < tables.getTable("RS2").get(i).size(); j++) {
                field.put(headerColumn.get(j), tables.getTable("RS2").get(i).get(headerColumn.get(j)));
            }
            datasourceList.add(field);
        }

        System.out.println("size datasourceList=>" + datasourceList);

        baos =new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        JRMapCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRMapCollectionDataSource(datasourceList);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                request.getServletContext().getRealPath("") + "/SCT/resources/newexcel.jasper", head, dataSource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, baos);
        reportStream=new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        System.out.println("done");

        return "success";
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        printStatement.print("in exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Here is the struts config for the action.

```
<action name="salesReportPdf" class="com.mindcraft.sct.action.SalesReportAction"
                method="salesReportPdf">
                <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
                <param name="inputName">reportStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="sales.pdf"               </param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            </result>
            <result name="error">/SCT/jsp/ErrorJasper.jsp</result>
            </action>
```

And i have made an ajax call for the action and proccess the data recieved.

```
<html>
    <body>
    ...
    <div id=pdfDiv>
        <object id=pdfview width="600" data="" type="application/pdf"></object>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    function exportType() {
                    debugger;
                    var type = $('#reportid').val();
                    alert(type);
                    if (type == "pdf") {
                        alert("in pdf condition");
                        $.ajax({
                            url : "salesReportPdf.action",
                            async : false,

                        }).done(function(data) {
                            alert("success");
                            var pdf = data;
                            alert(pdf);
                            $('#pdfview').html('<object data="'+ pdf + '"/>');
                            //$('#pdfview').attr('data', pdf);
                        });

                    }
```

but i am getting a gibberish data in the  tag.

��#����??�����*�������F����x��w1��?����ߠ=���?����#�^��5O���N�*���N�|���d��f��"�����i��i��II?r�?�:��m6n���U�?���<������VhYJ#�=��qx�bj���3��>��ھ����cmOu|�q��c+�>��J����Z������ͯQo�����P��F��/�5)�U#���W��b@0}M�e+_s���A�R�� ��Yj;f�(�k ���^vZ/(�3���/�CJ+�gN��``` -�ҭ����ջMl)?4q�\$�ņV˱P,��k�C�Ɛ�����\1�Y��٢��n�-��aY�XZ ���Ǻt�X!����``�:��0MNWs�n��Xj�g�d��y�+1�%�!5��|m!c��Njԓe��7� z�4�b�� �<ԋ�Ń4�@��%��c��n,�q:��>_���D�?V�ng�z[_��@�i� ```b�-c`��>]_O�w�o����|NA�2�����1��W66v��C��4Jڍ��\���&�o4 �C*��� �*aD?N���{ă֡�6�H�1-�.eC������:']B{#�Ԋj�g{0��� �E�������h��VI�>�O�F��z�#�BEb$H1� _b4�p�1P�����I;�摢>��(E

Please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: This is wrong format. You should use a dispatcher to render html.

Comment: @RomanC but i am using export to pdfStream and not html. And can u please explain it in more detail.
Thanks.

And to mention the action method is salesReportPdf and not salesReportHtml i wrote that by mistake

Comment: use ` <param name="contentDisposition">inline;filename="test.pdf"</param>`